# Disable Body Parameters in Query for Struts 1

Tags: servlets, struts-1

Regular use of the login page in the application uses a `DynaValidatorForm` that upon clicking 'submit' makes a POST request containing the username and password for the user. It is then validated and dealt with in the associated action class.

**Server code:**

```
protected ActionForward performAction(ActionMapping mapping,
        ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {    
    DynaValidatorForm dynaForm = (DynaValidatorForm) form;
    //validation here 
    //...
    //
    Login login = new Login();
    PropertyUtils.copyProperties(login, dynaForm);
    //login object is used from here on out
```

However, it is possible to log in by making a GET request with parameters in the URL i.e. `www.my-site.com/LoginPage.do?loginName=username&password=password`

**Is there some way to disable Struts from using URL parameters in the form?**

My current workaround is to use a filter that checks the query string and redirects if it contains a parameter that should be in the POST body, but I am looking for a more elegant solution. I cannot just disable GET as some other pages that need a similar solution need to be accessible by GET.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the requests' method and return from the action if it's GET

```
if(request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("GET")
    return mapping.findForward("error");
```